# Schooltool - how do I set up server?

Tags: installation

I am running Ubuntu 11.10. Gnome 3.2. Schooltool 1:1.7.

When I go to localhost:7080 and log in as administrator, there is no 'Server' menu, no School menu - as discussed in the documentation http://book.schooltool.org/server-settings.html.

What do I need to do to get that menu? I have installed the schooltool from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question or are you still looking for help? If you did find an answer please consider adding it here. Thanks :)

Comment: No. Did not get any answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install SchoolTool from the Ubuntu Software Center it gives you an older version of School Tool (not 2.0), which is different than what's shown in the current docs. That might be what happened; if so, follow the directions here http://book.schooltool.org/install-2_0.html